# Remove index fail in CodeInigter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to remove index.php in CI 3.x, i follow all tut in google and this is my code:

Controller

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Danhmuc extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //Load Dependencies

}
// List all your items
public function index( $offset = 0 )
{

}
public function add()
{
    $this->load->view('danhmuc/danhmuc');
}
}
?>
```

In views/danhmuc/danhmuc.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

In config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

And .htaccess in root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But when i try `http://localhost/cantin/danhmuc/add`, it's show 404 not found. But when i try `http://localhost/cantin/index.php/danhmuc/add` it's work. Hope you help me. Thank you!

My git: https://github.com/thanhhuy12th/CI3

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Comment: Do you enable rewrite mode on your web server?

Comment: @NguyenThanh rùi bạn ơi, mình enable rùi, bạn xem trong git có đúng ko?

Comment: @thanhhuy12thh Không bạn ơi, ý mình là enable nó ở web server cơ, ko phải trong code.

Comment: Minh enable rùi: sudo a2enmod rewrite, no cung báo thành công rùi, mình sài LAMP trên LINUX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your base url in config.php as it is required for CI 3 versions and up

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectfolder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

// Auto no longer in CI3

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

On routes.php

```
$route['danhmuc/add'] = 'danhmuc/add';
$route['danhmuc/(:any)'] = 'danhmuc/index/$1';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

For your htaccess try some of these

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Danhmuc extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index( $offset = 0 ) {
    }

    public function add(){
        $this->load->view('danhmuc/danhmuc');
    }
}
```

> On controllers, models, libraries, helpers, _lang files etc no need to use close `?>` at bottom

Answer (score 0):

change .htaccess  file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want to remove **index.php** from your url. Which is pretty simple.

Please try following:

In config.php don't change anything for url it will remain default:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And .htaccess in root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Send Request via index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `http://localhost/cantin/danhmuc/add` it's not change, but `http://localhost/cantin/index.php/danhmuc/add` it's work! 
Here my git: https://github.com/thanhhuy12th/CI3